# Computers unjoin domain after each reboot

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-name

This is my config:

```
controller.mydomain.local (Domain Controller)
     IP Address   : 192.168.1.1/24

computer1.mydomain.local
     IP Address   : 192.168.1.2/24 
     DNS Server 1 : 192.168.1.1 
     DNS Server 2 : 8.8.8.8 

computer2.mydomain.local
     IP Address   : 192.168.1.3/24 
     DNS Server 1 : 192.168.1.1 
     DNS Server 2 : 8.8.8.8
```

All these computers have the same username and password. After each reboot I can't ping `computer2.mydomain.local` or `computer1.mydomain.local` or `controller.mydomain.local` from `computer1` and `computer2`. I need to disable and enable network adapter 2 or 3 times, sometimes I need to reboot another time to be able to ping domain name or computer names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your computers are not unjoining the domain i.e. disappearing from your Active Directory. The **problem here is related to your DNS configuration**, alone. I believe that `ipconfig /all` shows:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.local
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.???
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

The problem here is that your DHCP server gives [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) `8.8.8.8` as a second DNS server. **Google Public DNS doesn't know anything about your local DNS names.** Every time a client computer tries to lookup `computer2.mydomain.local` from there it is doomed to fail. And this happens every time when the response from the first DNS server takes longer than a second.

Every time you reboot / disable&enable the adapter / unplug&plug the cable, it flushes the DNS cache, which causes you to *believe* it solved the problem, while the client only got temporarily the better condition of these two, i.e. the only DNS server that has the `mydomain.local` zone.

**Go to** *Administrative Tools* > *DHCP* > `controller.mydomain.local` > *Scope* `[192.168.1.0]` > *Scope Options* and **Remove** `8.8.8.8` from `006 DNS Servers`. (You should also add your another Domain Controller there instead, as you always should have at least two domain controllers.)

Then, if you wish to use `8.8.8.8` somewhere, add it as a [*forwarder* in your DNS server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754941(v=ws.11).aspx).